# How to add horizontal scroll in Material UI grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build kanban board with grid layout. there is seven columns in kanban boards. i have used materail Ui grid for each columns.

I have tried with below css but it's not working

`overflow: auto; 
   width:100%`

I have also tried with Single column gridlist but it also not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import App from "../components/App";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
     flexGrow: 1,
     marginTop: 30,
     display: 'flex',
     oveflow: "auto",
     maxWidth: "100%"
  },
  card: {
    minWidth: 180,
    marginBottom:20
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    maxWidth: 800,
    margin: `${theme.spacing.unit}px auto`,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
});

function SimpleCard(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;

  return (
    <App>
    <Header />
    <main className={classes.content}>
       <div className={classes.toolbar} />
       <div className={classes.paper}>

       <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={16}>
               <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                     <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 1
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 1
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 1
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 1
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                </Paper>

                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                        Word of the Day
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                        Task 1
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                        adjective
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
                </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 1
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day Testing
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 10000
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                            Word of the Day Testing
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            Task 11562
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                            adjective
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                </Paper>
                </Grid>
        </Grid>
       </div>
    </main>
    </App>
  );
}

SimpleCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SimpleCard);
```

How to add horizontal scroll in grid column layout?

Comment: plz provide a code example

Comment: I have added code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to put the `root` class on a `div` above the `Grid`?

Comment: @Jenian  I have try to put root class on div but its not working.

Comment: Can you prepare a live example plz?

Comment: Do you want to create horizontal scrollbar because your cards overlap?

Comment: @DominikTargosz I want to show all column (7 columns ) with horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that when you shrink the window of the browser then it appears horizontal scrollbar. Horizontal scrollball only appears when the content overflows outside the browser window. Try to set the width of your root wider than the wide of your browser window. For example 2000px. And delete the width: "100%"